# Formatting strings to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am trying to write keys and values from a dictionary in python to a csv file. I am getting the write output but I want to format it so it does not contain any '[]' or '"'. When I try:

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    # Tab delimited to allow for special characters
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    dic = {'2017-03-07': '36939142', '2014-02-19': '13193909'}
    for key in dic.keys():
        date = key
        order_number = dic[key]
        row = [date, order_number]
        datawriter.writerow([row])
```

I am looking for the output in the csv file to look like.
2017-03-07, 36939142. But instead in outputs this: ['2017-03-07, '36939142'].

How can I format it so I get the expected output?

Comment: you can join the row and then write it, `', '.join(row)`

Comment: You explain why you use tab as a delimiter in your comment in the code, but then expect the rows to be comma separated? If you want each item of your dict to appear as a tab-separated row of two values, simply change your last line to read `datawriter.writerow(row)` (note the removal of the square brackets  around `row`). Otherwise, I don't understand the point of setting `delimiter='\t'` when creating your writer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `datawriter.writerow(', '.join(row))` as the last line. Right now you're writing the data to the csv file as an array. The `', '.join(ar)` syntax takes each part of the array in parenthesis and concatenates them together with a comma in  between them

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    # Tab delimited to allow for special characters
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    dic = {'2017-03-07': '36939142', '2014-02-19': '13193909'}
    for key in dic.keys():
        datawriter.writerow("%s, %s" % (key, dic[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with your solution you can change the last but one line to

```
row = f"{date}, {order_number}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can achieve it as follows

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    # Tab delimited to allow for special characters
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    dic = {'2017-03-07': '36939142', '2014-02-19': '13193909'}
    for key,value in dic.items():
        datawriter.writerow("{0}, {1}".format(key,value))
```